# REGEX Validation Rule to prevent duplicate in set of numbers

Tags: formula, validation, validation-rule, regular-expressions

I'm working on a validation that would require a user to enter only numbers that have to be exactly 9 numbers and be separated by lines. The below is working for that, but is it possible with straight RegEx to add criteria prevent a duplicate of any number set?

```
!REGEX(SomeCustomField__c, '^[0-9]{9}+(\r\n[0-9]{9}+)*$')
```

If there way you can prevent a number from appearing twice without Apex?

```
123456789
123456780
// Prevent duplicate of any number already entered
123456789
123456780
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, regex can do this.

```
NOT(REGEX(SomeCustomField__c, '^(?s)\\d{9}(\\s+\\d{9})$')) ||
REGEX(SomeCustomField__c, '(?s)(\\d{9}).*\\1')
```

The trick here is that we go in to "single line mode" `(?s)` to allow `.` to match newlines, then we check each nine-digit string `(\\d{9})` with any intervening characters (`.*`), followed by the same group again (`\\1`).

Comment: I should have thought of using an AND expression. Having a bit of an issue as it doesn't seem to work in the same validation rule from what I can see. If I separate them into different validation rules it works as intended. Let me double-check a few things.

Comment: @AndrewL. I actually meant OR. Silly mistake, really.

Comment: No problem. It gave me an opportunity to work with REGEX and validation. Thanks again.